# Can't get rid of header on scraped data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the below code that scrapes this site: https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/index.html

It scrapes the links and titles about a quarter of the way down the page. Additionally, it opens up each link and scrapes all the text on each page. Here's an example of one of those pages: https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2024/02/06/hhs-office-civil-rights-settles-malicious-insider-cybersecurity-investigation.html

It works well except all the description fields start off with this: "An official website of the United States government Here’s how you know
Official websites use .gov
A .gov website belongs to an official government organization in the United States.

Secure .gov websites use HTTPS
A lock (LockA locked padlock) or https:// means you’ve safely connected to the .gov website. Share sensitive information only on official, secure websites.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of that? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from urllib.parse import urljoin***

# Function to scrape text from a given URL
def scrape_page_text(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    # Find all paragraphs and concatenate their text
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
    text = ' '.join([p.get_text() for p in paragraphs])
    return text

# Base URL
base_url = "https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/"

# URL of the page to scrape
url = urljoin(base_url, "index.html")

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the innermost l-content div
content_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='l-content')
content_div = content_divs[-1]

# Find all <a> tags containing the links within the innermost div
links = content_div.find_all('a')

# Create and open a CSV file in write mode
with open('hipaa_links.csv', mode='w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Create a CSV writer object
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'URL', 'Description'])

    # Iterate over each link
    for link in links:
        # Extract link URL
        link_url = urljoin(base_url, link.get('href'))

        # Extract link title
        link_title = link.text.strip()

        # Scrape text from the linked page
        description = scrape_page_text(link_url)

        # Check if both link URL and title exist
        if link_url and link_title:
            writer.writerow([link_title, link_url, description])

print("Data has been written to hipaa_links.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated `scrape_page_text()` function that gets only the text of the content:

```py
# Function to scrape text from a given URL
def scrape_page_text(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # Find all paragraphs and concatenate their text
    paragraphs = soup.select(".l-content p")
    text = " ".join([p.get_text() for p in paragraphs])
    return text
```

---

EDIT: How to scrap link texts + dates:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/index.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select(".usa-prose a"):
    date = link.find_next_sibling(string=True)
    if date is None:
        date = ""
    else:
        date = date.strip(" \xa0-")

    print(f"{link.text[:50]:<50} {date}")
```

Prints:

```
...

First HIPAA enforcement action for lack of timely  January 9, 2017
UMass settles potential HIPAA violations following November 22, 2016
$2.14 million HIPAA settlement underscores importa October 17, 2016
HIPAA settlement illustrates the importance of rev September 23, 2016
Advocate Health Care Settles Potential HIPAA Penal August 4, 2016
Multiple alleged HIPAA violations result in $2.75  July 21, 2016
Widespread HIPAA vulnerabilities result in $2.7 mi July 18, 2016
Business Associate’s Failure to Safeguard Nursing  June 29, 2016
Unauthorized Filming for “NY Med” Results in $2.2  April 21, 2016
$750,000 settlement highlights the need for HIPAA  
Improper disclosure of research participants’ prot March 17, 2016
$1.55 million settlement underscores the importanc March 16, 2016
Physical therapy provider settles violations that  February 16, 2016
Administrative Law Judge rules in favor of OCR enf February 3, 2016

...
```

Comment: Thank you!! One other question...if you look at that first link (https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/index.html), all the urls/titles have a date after them (i.e. HHS’ Office for Civil Rights Settles Malicious Insider Cybersecurity Investigation for $4.75 Million - February 6, 2024). I can't for the life of me figure out how to scrape those. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks! Some of the dates output as this though "– May 8, 2023" due to inconsistent formatting of the site. Any way around that you think?

Comment: @user23471091 Probably the `–` is different as `-`. You can try to add `–` to the `.strip()` method.